# Definition: Mathematical way to define the "left" and the "right"

Tags: logic, definition, physics, axioms

**How do we define the left and the right, (such as left/right handness) from a mathematical way of definition? How can we explain this definition to some inhabitant of a distant stellar system who has not yet learned the concept of left and right?**

In particle physics, we have left-right asymmetry for weak interactions in particle physics: see http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1957/press.html

> "Let us assume that the magnetic field is created by means of a coil placed like a spool of thread on a table, and that the electric current is flowing counterclockwise in the wire. Then the north poles of the cobalt nuclei will be directed upwards. The experiment, now, gave the result that the electrons from the radioactive process with this arrangement were preferentially thrown downwards towards the floor. From this it follows unambiguously that the process lacks that right-left symmetry, which one had earlier assumed. Thus, by means of this experiment it could be explained to a person, who did not know it - let us say an inhabitant of a distant stellar system - what we mean by right and left. In fact, it would be sufficient to ask him to arrange the experiment so as to make the preferential direction of the electrons point downwards. The current will then have the same direction as that in which he has to turn at the command "left face". ...  In stating this we have tacitly made an assumption which is not quite confirmed as yet but which, as far as the experiments go, seems probable, namely that the results of all experiments performed with the opposite kind of elementary particles would be just such as to reestablish the right-left symmetry. "

**Question: I am asking a mathematical definition or communication on the concept of the left and the right.**

Comment: Are you implying that some being who doesn't know the definition of left/right would know the definition of clockwise or counterclockwise?  It is like asking whether we define positive current as the motion of electrons or the motion of holes.  At some point, some term or frame of reference would need to be defined.  Else, by reorienting your viewpoint you get a different result.  Perhaps if you were to physically provide the tool to run the experiment, however, if you were to provide instructions on how to create it themselves without pictures, or defining left/right/clockwise...

Comment: I doubt it's possible.

Comment: Can one of the categorists on this site please categorify "left-right?"

Comment: I think by the time we are able to find an inhabitant of a distant solar system to whom we would want to explain the idea we will know how to do it... chances are, assuming they exist, they will find us first and will already understand those scientific/mathematical principles.

Comment: @TravisJ: It's not really a mathematical principle, though.  It can be expressed in that domain, but not really represented in the sense that one can communicate the meaning and distinctions of left and right only through those expressions.  Even on our world, left and right are communicated out of band.  I agree with Julien that given only abstract notions, one seemingly cannot define left and right unambiguously.  The physical world is defined by nature, and if she gives us a case of symmetry-breaking, we can use it.  Mathematics, apparently, affords us no such opportunity.

Comment: How would you define it? Do you think it has something to do with **humans** being the conscious entities discussing mathematics on a website built by other humans? After their parent's parent's parent's ... ancestor's ancestor's ... ancestor's ancestor being an algae in the ocean soup of amino acids. Then eventually some of its descendants started to grow arms, then gained consciousness, and asked one day: _"What are these appendages coming out of my body?"_ If you meditate a bit on it you might still be able to reach parts of your subconscious, and have a chat with it on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

## A theoretical definition

In math, the most basic definition would be something like "If you move so that you're at the origin in 3-d, and you rotate so that 'up' is in the direction of (0,0,1) and 'forward' is in the direction of (1,0,0), then 'left' is in the direction of (0,1,0) and 'counter-clockwise' is turning from (1,0,0) to (0,1,0) through the shortest angle." If you know about vector algebra, then you can skip the rotation and translation: if $\vec u$ is up and $\vec v$ is forward (necessarily orthogonal to $\vec u$), then left is the cross product $\vec u\times \vec v$.

## A real world caveat

The problem is that the definition above only matches the real world usage of "left" if you draw the coordinate axes in the conventional way. And if you aren't next to the alien to show them how you draw the axes, the definition above won't solve that unless you already agree on the meaning of "left". This is why the question of "is there a universal thing to identify the direction of left?" is one of physics.

Comment: IIRC if your alien is in a part of the universe made of antimatter, using the weak interactions would give them the opposite of the correct idea. I think Feynman made a joke about not shaking hands with an alien who presents the wrong one.

Comment: That's a good joke, but I've never heard it before. So I doubt that it was Feynman.

Comment: @TonyK, it was definitely Feynman. Do a search for the text: Extend your right hand,” you say, to which the alien responds, “What is right

Comment: @MarkS. While I believe that was true at the time, it has since been determined that CP violation is  *also* a thing in physics. Kaons decay in a way that violates both charge and parity symmetry, so it's possible to set up an experiment that identifies whether you're made of matter or antimatter and that experiments also physically defines left.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mathematical defination of LEFT and RIGHT.There is neither

a position called LEFT nor RIGHT in the real world. In a big space

your own position tells that what is right and what left.It is with

respect to you.So left and right positions are thought of with respect

to something.Think that you are in the space,then symmetric law of the

universe tells wherever you position is,you are the centre of the

universe.There you can't decide what is right side or left side.So

there is no exact defination of LEFT and RIGHT without with respect to

something.If there will exist a defination of what you have asked for

,it must be independent of any invented theory till date.But this can't

happen because we measure or think or calculate with respect to something.