# Prove this conjecture: Two lists of vectors are in the same orientation iff this transformation exists

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant, rotations, conjectures

Can you please help prove or disprove my conjecture below?

**Definition:** Given vector space $V$ of $n$ dimensions, and ordered lists $x, y$ such that $x,y \subset V$; $x,y$ are each linearly independent; and $x,y$ each span $V$, then $x$ and $y$ are said to be of the *same orientation* if there exists a linear transformation $R$ such that:

1. $R(V) = V$
2. $\det R = 1$
3. For all $i \leq n$, $y_i$ is in the span of $\{x_1 ... x_i\}$ with the coefficient of $x_i$ nonnegative.  Formally, this is: For each $i \leq n$ there exists an ordered list $S_i$ of $i$ scalars $\{S_{i_1}, S_{i_2}, ..., S_{i_i}\}$ with $S_{i_i} \geq 0$ such that $R(x_i) = \sum_{j \leq i} S_{i_j} y_j$.

**Conjecture:** Let $X$ be a matrix in any basis where column $i$ of $X$ is $x_n$, and let $Y$ be similarly constructed from $y$ in the same basis.  Then $x$ and $y$ are in the same orientation if and only if $\det XY > 0$.

**Corollaries:**

1. *Same orientation* is an equivalence relation
2. An even permutation of list $x$ or $y$ preserves sameness of orientation; an odd permutation alters it
3. If $a,b$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, then $a, b, a \times b$ are in the same orientation as $e_1, e_2, e_3$.

**Motivation:** The Right Hand Rule is used throughout physics as well as in well-respected vector calculus books, such as Hubbard or Colley.  Yet, [it's hard if not impossible to formulate the RHR without reference to anatomy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665280/can-a-purely-mathematical-version-of-the-right-hand-rule-be-given).  The above (if proven true!) is an attempt to do so in a mathematically rigorous way.

I'd add a fourth "corollary": If a person views themselves as living inside $\mathbb R^3$, with $e_1, e_2, e_3$ drawn as conventional (to the right, forward, and up, respectively), then their right hand's thumb, pointer, and middle finger are in the same orientation as $e_1, e_2, e_3$.

Is that conjecture true? Can you help me prove it?  What would $R$ look like? (Point #3 reminds me of a triangular matrix.  Perhaps $R$ could be specified as $PTP^{-1}$, where $\det P = 1$ and $T$ is triangular?).  Can we find $R$?

Comment: Point 1. is useless, in view of point 2. In point 3, your first sentence is not related to $R,$ and the "formal" second sentence is far from equivalent to the first one.

Comment: A simpler and well-known definition of "$x$ and $y$ have the same orientation" (but equivalent to yours once you will have corrected it) is: $\det_x(y)>0$, i.e. positivity of the determinant of the matrix whose columns are the coordinates of the $y_j$'s in the basis $x.$ With this definition, your conjecture becomes obvious.